# Do US Citizens need transit visas for New Delhi airport?

Tags: transit, us-citizens, transit-visas, new-delhi

I am travelling from JFK to KTM via New Delhi, India. My transit time is around 16 hours in New Delhi. Do I have to get transit visa in New Delhi to stay in the airport?

Comment: What passport do you hold?

Comment: @Anju            You need to add your passport information. Do you have a dual nationality or Indian Passport with Entry Visa? Or Just a US passport?

Comment: I have my new USA passport but my india visa is still valid so do I have to transfer visa on my new passport or I can travel with my old passport with valid visa to india

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=IN&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa) Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

So if the trip is in a single booking, you do **not** need a visa

Answer (score -1):

US citizen or not, you need Transit Visa if you are not Indian. Although there are visa exceptions for 10 countries Japan, Luxembourg, New Zealand, Cambodia, Singapore, Finland, Laos, Indonesia, Philippines, etc.

The visa service is outsourced to VFS global (UK and RotW) and BLS International (for USA) who deal with multiple countries' visa applications. Here is the link for [Indian Visa services in the USA](http://www.visa.blsindia-usa.com/)

You probably have to visit [this page](http://www.visa.blsindia-usa.com/transitVisa.php)

One thing is that you have not mentioned in your passport whether or not you hold the dual citizenship (or if you are an Indian-American). In anyway, the links that I provided above should do the job for you.

Comment: There is no dual-citizenship (like Indian-American). However, India has a special entry document called the OCI for people of Indian origin who acquired foreign citizenship.

Comment: This answer is wrong. India allows visa-free airside transit